# Java process memory used 3.2GB, but heap used only 1053MB, I want to know how to solve this

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jvm, heap-memory

I want to check the backends' healthy condition, I use the ThreadPool start a Thread to check backend per10s. In this times, this will query mysql 6 times per 10s and not use the database connection pool.
When I deploy this app in the cloud platform, I received message that the usage of memory is continued growth.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yBnt.png)

At first, I use the `top` command to watch the usage of Java Heap.
In this picture, I find this app use about 3.2GB memory.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etpOI.png)

And then I exec the `jmap -heap 9`,but i find the heap usage of memory is only 1053MB.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18PZK.png)

I guess the reason of this is the number of thread. I exec the `pstree -p | grep java | wc -l`. I find only 70 threads.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3p4TQ.png)

Finally, I exec the `jcmd 9 VM.native_memory scale=MB`. I see the Heap usage of memory is 4096MB. This confused me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1BoB.png)

I want to decrease the usage of memory in this app. But I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: There are a multitude of profiling tools designed specifically to help for things like this.  JProfiler is the one I can remember off the top of my head, but I'm certain there are others.  You could also remote debug/just plain debug it to get a better look at what's going on internally.

Comment: tx~, I try it right now